# Redux connect with state shorthand

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

I am looking at [this example](https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/tree/master/examples/navigation).

However, I found this(`containers/UserSearch.jsx`) hard to understand:

```
export default connect(
  ({ routing, userResults, searchInFlight }) => ({
    query: routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.q,
    results: userResults,
    searchInFlight
  }),
  { searchUsers }
)(UserSearch);
```

The point is, the `routing` reducer didn't even imported. And how was this supposedly `mapStateToProps` function possible?

Please help explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the `connect` api, it describes the following arguments is passed to it.

```
connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
```

The first one is `mapStateToProps` which in your case is a function.

```
({ routing, userResults, searchInFlight }) => ({
 query: routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.q,
 results: userResults,
 searchInFlight
})
```

The first argument to this function is the whole redux state. Your syntax `{ routing, userResults, searchInFlight }` is called as [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), where you pick only the said variables from the state. So `routing`, `userResults`, `searchInFlight` are all nodes of your redux state.

The `routing` node which is in question should have been added by the `routingReducer` when you did `combineReducers` earlier while creating the state. So here `routing` is just a node in your state that holds the routing related data as specified by `RoutingReducer` and is not the routing reducer itself.

Finally inside your function, you return a `plain object`(probably constructed using the variables you extracted out of the state), which will be merged with the `props` that is passed to the Component(`UserSearch`)

This is the reason why the argument is named `mapStateToProps` which denotes, that you map the redux state with or without manipulations and pass it as props to the component as you require.

**EDIT**

The first argument is [`de-structuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `state` object and is extracting the mentioned values to a separate variables. The below code is interchangeable.

```
({ routing, userResults, searchInFlight }) => ({
 query: routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.q,
 results: userResults,
 searchInFlight
})
```

is equivalent to write

```
(state) => {
 let routing = state.routing;
 let userResults = state.userResults;
 let searchInFlight = sate.searchInFlight;
 return {
  query: routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.q,
  results: userResults,
  searchInFlight: searchInFlight
 }
}
```

is equivalent to write

```
(state) => ({
 query: state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.query.q,
 results: state.userResults,
 searchInFlight: state.searchInFlight
})
```

Destructuring assignment is just a short hand to extract the needed values and assign it to local variable which you can use. I don't see a performance issue. The only advantage i can see is that even if the state has 1000 properties, we retrieve only the ones which we need and use them.

Comment: Still baffled, the whole block of code didn't mention the `state` object, how's that?Normally, there will be something like this: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ ...state.auth });`

Comment: Your `({ routing, userResults, searchInFlight })` is extracting these mentioned variables from the state object. `({auth}) => {}` and using `auth` is equivalent to write `(state) => {}` and using `state.auth`.

Comment: The keyword here is `Destructuring-assignment`, further knowledge learned from https://egghead.io/lessons/ecmascript-6-destructuring-assignment. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why the first one is adopted. The second one seems more readable. Performance issue?